# Where can I download a compiled jUnit 5 jar package?

Tags: junit

I just need `.jar` files for JUnit 5. From the repo and website, it seems that they want you to compile/build them yourself using Maven... right?

However, I don't have the ability to compile/build in Maven (or whatever other tools you'd use normally). Is there an easy way to just get the compiled `.jar` files, like there used to be for [JUnit 4](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install)?

If not, is there a simple way to build for someone not familiar with Maven or other environments? (I am coding in a tool that uses Java but is anything like Maven/IntelliJ...)

Or is it safe to use 3rd-party downloads of the jar files [like this one](https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/junit5)?

any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junit 5 is not distributed in a single artifact just like Junit4,
All the relevant jars containing the compiled code are in [the maven central repository](https://central.sonatype.com/search?namespace=org.junit.jupiter) but you'll need to know what exactly to download

To understand exactly what are the relevant jars for your installation google for "JUnit 5 architecture". Here is one [link](https://www.educative.io/courses/java-unit-testing-with-junit-5/xV9mMjj74gE) that explains it pretty well